# Increase transactional email deliverability

Tags: spam-prevention, transactional-email

My question is strictly related to transactional emails and common best practices like using different email providers for transactional and marketing emails, relevant Subject, From and Reply-To addresses, etc. is assumed.

**Would using multiple transactional email providers with a different affinity to the destination domain or even full email address increase my deliverability?**

e.g. using let's say mandrill to send to gmail and postmark for everything else or even mandrill for user1@gmail.com and postmark for user2@gmail.com

**Is it worth splitting transactional emails in first class ones (reset password, verify email, etc) and second class ones (merely informative) and using different email providers for each?**

e.g. using mandrill for password reset and postmark for the welcome (registration successful) email

**What else is advisable?**

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you got the thread rightly.

For transactional emails, it is always recommended to go with a highly reputed service provider who doesn't deal with spam or promotional emails. This is the first most step. If the vendor supports both then there is a high probability that they will end up messing the reputation of your domain/IP addresses.

As you have selected a good provider, so you can be now rest assured your emails are following the best delivery practices and are compliance with guidelines.

Now, the second step is to have a separate account for the marketing emails. This can be with the current vendor (only if the vendor providers different envelope and IP addresses for this account) or with a new service provider.

Now, the third step is to have a separate domain/sub-domain (preferably sub-domain, so that you should not look spammy to the world) for marketing emails.e.g. if you are using example.com for your transactional account, then use mailer-example.com for your marketing account.

Another important note, having a separate account doesn't mean you now save to send any type of promo/marketing, send relevant customer engaging emails else by doing all these hacks also, you will end up losing the reputation of your sender domain and delivery IP addresses.

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't answer my questions. What you wrote is assumed. I'm asking about using multiple reputable transactional email providers for transactional emails. I'll update the question maybe that'll help.

Comment: If your volume is huge then you can choose multiple ESP just for the backup.

Deliverability will depend upon your target list and target campaign. 
User engagement will decide your deliverability. If you sending good engaging campaign than you will get good delivery else none of the ESP will give you good delivery on your campaign.

It always good practices to maintain two or three envelope domain if your volume is huge (sending Millions of emails a day). You can use a different envelope for your transaction and promo volume.

Comment: This is not about volume and since these are transactional emails engagement is fine. It's just a reality that transactional email providers don't have a 100% deliverability rate themselves. I'm thinking about taking advantage of this marginal variation somehow if possible. Again these are NOT marketing campaigns.

Answer (score 0):

So all of the major transactional email providers offer similar deliverability abilities, they (obviously) take that stuff very seriously.

I don't think splitting between them is worth it, but there are some things you can do to increase your delivery rates and inbox placement regardless of ESP:

1. By default you share a delivery IP with other ESP customers, if you pay more you can get a dedicated IP which will improve things over the long term (assuming your data is good)
2. Reduce bounces -- using [an email verification service](https://kickbox.com) when you collect an email to make sure it is a real, active email address will reduce bounce rates and improve the deliverability of your emails. I work for [Kickbox](https://kickbox.com), which offers exactly this.
3. Reducing spam complaints -- make sure users know the emails are coming from your web app and you make it clear how to turn the emails off.

Hope that helps.